# How to update two UITableviewCell data simultaneously?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uitextview

I am working with Xcode8.2.1.My custom cell contain only one UITextview.When I am trying to type on fist cell it must be automatically enter data to second cell.The cell also must be grow with proper height.Now its working for only one cell is growing.I want to grow two cells simultaneously when i am typing data on UITextview of first cell. Please go through the following code.

```
//Tableview Datasource method

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: TranslateTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TranslateTableViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! TranslateTableViewCell

        if let traduzioneVal = self.traduzioneArray[indexPath.row]["ione"] {
            cell.translateTextView.text = traduzioneVal

        }
        cell.cellIndexPath = indexPath
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }


//custom delegate method calling from textViewDidChange
    func updateTextView(indexPath: IndexPath, comment: String) {

          self.traduzioneArray[indexPath.row]["ione"] = comment
          self.traduzioneArray[indexPath.row + 1]["ione"] = comment
          self.lyricsTableView.beginUpdates()
          self.lyricsTableView.endUpdates()
}

//UItextview Delegate method (from custom TranslateTableViewCell class )
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
                self.delegate.updateTextView(indexPath: self.cellIndexPath, comment: textView.text)
     }
```

Comment: so why not call section/row reload on beginUpdates() ... endUpdates()?

Comment: @Joshua, I tried  this self.lyricsTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic). But it does not work and it also automatically dismiss keyboard.

Comment: Do you just have two cells, one with the original text and one with the translated text? Maybe you could just have two `UITextView`s instead of your table.